# How to know my commands history

Tags: bash

> ***I don't know Why I've downvoted in such manner but still I need an answer***

I know that I can easily know my commands history by just running the command `history`.

But two major consequences raise here:

1. `history -c` command will just flush the history
2. A command with space before will not stored in the history

So if I run the command `history -c` or a command with space before or other commands such as `^bad^good` as @AvinashRaj stated, thus I can't reshow them using the `history` command.

So is there another way to know all commands ran before?!!

Also the the marked as duplicate sure will not answer my question. It's just a monitoring to terminal and not command history.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you want to be able to learn your history even when it was flushed, resp. disable the white-space-command-doesn't-go-into-history feature?

Comment: My question is clear. I want to know the commands history whatever done

Comment: So you want to have your history show the 'history -c' command when issued and also the commands that started with a space?

Comment: `sudo !!` command also wouldn't be stored in the history.

Comment: @TimothyPersoon Yes

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks buddy but it will no affect since it just repeat the last command which will be listed

Comment: And also this command `^bad^good`

Comment: It's not quite clear to me neather (don't understand why they gave a -2 though, it is a relevant question). Anyway, how about something like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session ...does it help you?

Comment: Are you using bash?

Comment: @Braiam yes I'm so

Answer (score 4):

The bash terminal commands history for a user is stored in `$HOME/.bash_history` file. The commands used in the `tty` session will be written to the `.bash_history` file when the `tty` session is terminated; but running `history -c` command will prevent them from being appended in the history file. What `history` command does is it displays the contents of the `$HOME/.bash_history`. (You can also check and/or edit the file with text editors, say with `nano $HOME/.bash_history`.)

---

> *"A command with a space before it won't be stored.., `!!` or duplicate commands won't be stored, etc."*

You can change the settings according to your needs by making changed in `$HOME/.bashrc` file. This post explains how: [Get bash history to remember only the commands run with space prefixed!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423707/get-bash-history-to-remember-only-the-commands-run-with-space-prefixed).

And in this file you may find lines like:

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

**HISTSIZE** is the number of commands to remember in the *command history*. The default value is `500`.

**HISTFILESIZE** is *maximum number of lines* contained in the history file.  When this variable is assigned a value, the history  file  is  truncated,  if  necessary,  by removing the oldest entries, to contain no more than that number of lines.  The default value is `500`. The history file is also truncated to this size after writing it when an interactive shell exits.

---

So, to summarize `history -c` just clears the running `tty` session's history and the previous commands should still be accessible with `history` command provided the older commands are not truncated as per the **HISTFILESIZE <= max_lines** constraint.

Comment: That's good friend